# How to make the conjugate transpose

Tags: matrix, complex

I have a problem to make the conjugate and transpose the matrix.May anyone help me please.

```
MatrixForm[{{E^(I*β1 + I*β3) Cos[β2], 
   E^(I β1 - 
       I*β3) Sin[β2]}, {(-E^((-I) β1 + 
         I*β3)) Sin[β2], 
   E^((-I) β1 - I*β3)*Cos[β2]}}]
```

and I get the output

```
{{E^((-I)*Conjugate[β1] - I*Conjugate[β3])*
   Conjugate[Cos[β2]], 
  -(E^(I*Conjugate[β1] - I*Conjugate[β3])*
    Conjugate[Sin[β2]])}, 
 {E^((-I)*Conjugate[β1] + I*Conjugate[β3])*
   Conjugate[Sin[β2]], 
  E^(I*Conjugate[β1] + I*Conjugate[β3])*
   Conjugate[Cos[β2]]}}
```

my problem here, I just want to conjugate the imaginary part but it conjugate all include the angle Cos and Sin (real). How can I solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) with [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html):

```
m = {{E^(I*β1 + I*β3) Cos[β2], 
    E^(I β1 - I*β3) Sin[β2]}, {(-E^((-I) β1 + I*β3)) Sin[β2], 
    E^((-I) β1 - I*β3)*Cos[β2]}};

MatrixForm[
 Assuming[{β1, β2, β3} ∈ Reals, 
  Simplify@ConjugateTranspose[m]]]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  e^{i \text{$\beta $1}+i \text{$\beta $3}} \cos
>    (\text{$\beta $2}) & e^{i \text{$\beta $1}-i
>    \text{$\beta $3}} \sin (\text{$\beta $2}) \\
>  -e^{i \text{$\beta $3}-i \text{$\beta $1}} \sin
>    (\text{$\beta $2}) & e^{-i \text{$\beta $1}-i
>    \text{$\beta $3}} \cos (\text{$\beta $2}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$